# What is compaction term related to Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to understand the compaction feature of Couchbase. I would also like to know the best time to compact my bucket and why compacting a bucket is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase uses an append-only file for writing data to disk.  Since this file is append-only it means that every time you write to it the file gets larger. This is the case whether or not you are adding new data or updating existing data.

If you just continue writing data to an append-only file then eventually you will run out of disk space unless you reclaim this space by removing no longer used portions of the file. This process is called compaction. Below is an simple example of how compaction works.

Imagine having a file that is append only and has key value data.

key1, value1
key2, value2
key3, value3

If you update key1 the file will look like this

<strike>key1, value1</strike>
key2, value2
key3, value3
key1, value4

As you can see the file grew due to the update. After the compaction process runs the file would look like this:

key2, value2
key3, value3
key1, value4

This is a very simplified example of how compaction works and it is much more complicated in append-only data stores.

In Couchbase it is recommended that you schedule compaction to run at night (or at a time when your application is has the lowest usage). The reason is that compaction is a disk intensive task. If you cannot just run compaction at night it will start automatically if a file has a certain amount of fragmentation (unused data) in the file. At the end of the day though it really depends on your deployment and workload characteristics, but most people find that the Couchbase defaults work fine for them.

Comment: One other things to make sure is obvious is that the compaction operates on one vBucket at a time, not the entire database. The Couchbase defaults are to run compaction only when a each vBucket data file gets 30% fragmented on that one vBucket. So more than likely as Mike pointed out, the default schedule will serve you well.